# Postgres Public Synonym Issue

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, synonyms

PostgreSQL ver 9.4.5.  Linux OS.
Application:  Web Based

Platform:

```
App Server (java) --> jdbc call --> Database Server (PostgreSQL)
```

I do know that PostgreSQL does not support the public synonym.  Now, for a user schema (let's call it MASTER_USER), if I coded in the stored function/procedure like the following, without using a public synonym to identify the table name:

```
select user_name from user_info_table;
```

then access it from the Java (web app) side via the JDBC call to the database, will that work?

OR,

I must use the identifier inside the sql, such as:

```
select user_name from  MASTER_USER.user_info_table?
```

I come from the Oracle world, there I first create the public synonym for the table, then in the stored procedure I just directly reference the table with no need to identify the table with a schema name.  I'd like to know how it works under PostgreSQL.

Comment: Adjust the `search_path` - which is the answer you already got on the mailing list: http://postgresql.nabble.com/public-synonym-td5880945.html

Comment: you can set search_path for a stored procedure too, but this is a less common option.